# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS slow on a MacBook Pro

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, xfce, macbook-pro

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my MacBook Pro (there is a reason I need this specific version and not a more recent one), along with the Xfce4 desktop manager (because of being supposedly lightweight - I've tried the default one as well but to no avail). The installation was done on a separate 70GB partition (with 10GB swap space).

Now, the thing is it's mostly **very laggy**. At times, it does work fine, but it quickly slows down a lot (right now, as I'm speaking, even typing or scrolling in Chrome is super laggy). Also, the fan occasionally spins like there's no tomorrow (perhaps indicating something going wrong with the perceived CPU temperature?).

And before I start blaming my MacBook Pro, let's say it's an early 2011 model, with a core i5 on it, 8GB of ram installed, and a brand new SSD.

The system runs macOS High Sierra (the latest version) and Windows 10 flawlessly, without any delays whatsoever. And it lags with Ubuntu? I mean... what type of joke is that?!

Any ideas what might be going on?

Any suggestion will be appreciated! :)

---

**Update:**

Tried installing `macfanctld` as suggested somewhere. After installing it, I saw no real difference. BUT: After rebooting, it seems to be working like a breeze. But let's see how it goes... (Perhaps it has nothing to do with this new package?)

**Update 2:** [20 minutes later]

The fan is sure working a lot (but perhaps, it generally works quite a lot) and the whole system seems to be working great. Not just great, it's like super-fast.

**Update 3:** [Hours later]

I think this did the trick. :)

Comment: Is it only Chrome that misbehaves?

Comment: @DKBose Nope, it's a general issue. Even dragging a window around is  laggy. Even typing in the terminal has a lag!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, as I discovered the solution was to install `macfanctld`:

```
sudo apt install macfanctld
```

After that, it all works smoothly.

Comment: I'd say `mbpfan` is better as it is maintained. Discussion: https://github.com/MikaelStrom/macfanctld/issues/19